# Remove by rows from a data frame with respect to a list of values

Tags: dataframe, slice

I have a categorical variable X in my data frame which contains 10 levels. I have constructed a list with 3 of those 10 levels. I would like to drop rows from the data frame for all those rows where the variable levels are not in the list.

I have tried:

```
level_list= ['l1','l2','l3']
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if (df['X'].iloc[i] in level_list) == False:
        df.drop(i, axis=0)
```

However none of the rows in the data frame is dropped. I need some help on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) is what you're looking for.

```
df[df['X'].isin(level_list)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.loc[df['X'].apply(lambda x: x in level_list)]
```

should do the trick.

With

```
df['X'].apply(lambda x: x in level_list)
```

you are getting a "filter mask" for your whole DataFrame and then apply the filter mask with *.loc*